# How to schedule airplane mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, airplane-mode

I want to schedule Airplane Mode during the night (10PM–6AM) on my iPhone.

How can I do that?

I used to turn off my previous phone (a non-smartphone). I do that especially to save some battery life.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is possible in iOS 14 using the Shortcuts app. You have to create an automation to enable the airplane mode in the evening and another automation to disable it in the morning.

I used the following:

1. Create automation
2. At `22:30` → `Airplane mode ON`
3. Disable “Ask before running”
4. Finish

The same process for the morning

1. Create automation
2. At `5:30` → `Airplane mode OFF`
3. Disable “Ask before running”
4. Finish

**Another approach.**

On the other side, since many would want to schedule the Airplane during the night, I can recommend from my own experience that leaving the  devices (phone, computer, tablet), in a different room than the bedroom is a good idea.

I built this habit in the last months and I use my CASIO watch to wake me up every morning.

Answer (score 6):

For iOS 12 and older, it's not possible to schedule *Airplane Mode* unless you have a jailbroken device.  If you want to jailbreak your iPhone, there's a few apps that do this exact thing.

This sounds like it would be a good idea so I recommend you let Apple know you want this on their iPhone [Feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) page.